# Why get I this error message, if I want to read from the User collection the id property?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

**app.js**

```
app.get("/userid", function(req, res){
    User.findById(req.params._id, function(err, foundUser){
        if(err){
            res.redirect("/home");
        }else{
            res.render("userid", {User: foundUser});
        }
    });
});
```

**userid.ejs**

```
<%- include ("partials/header") %>
<h1>Userid List</h1>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <p><%= User._id %></p>
        </div>
</div>
<%- include ("partials/footer") %>
```

**Error message:**

> Cannot read property '_id' of null

If I check the mongo from the terminal, I can see, that user collection with id property exist.
Why get I this error message?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please console.log(foundUser) above the render command

Comment: @Mahesh Bhatnagar null

Comment: So that this error comes Cannot read property '_id' of null

Comment: Because there are no params I think. Please change the path to app.get("/:userId), notice the ":". Then try logging the req.params again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

//app.js

```
   app.get("/userid", function(req, res){
    User.find({}, function(err, foundUser){
        if(err){
            res.redirect("/home");
        }else{
            console.log(foundUser);
            res.render("userid", {User: foundUser});
        }
    });
   });
```

I used the find() function instead of findById() and I dont got error message anymore, but I can't see the ids on the userid.ejs page -> iteration with forEach() added.

//userid.ejs

```
<%- include ("partials/header") %>
<h1>Userid List</h1>
<div class="container">
    <% User.forEach(function(User){ %>
        <div class="row">
            <p><%= User._id %></p>
        </div>
    <% }); %>
</div>
<%- include ("partials/footer") %>
```

Now it's working fine!
Does anyone know, why didn't work the findById() in this case?